# Changing HTML Object Property

Tags: javascript, html, object, events

I have a dynamic form validation event listener, which checks if an input is valid or not.

However, even when the input technically isn't valid, the HTML Object Property validity -> Valid is set to "True".

I cant figure out how I can trigger it to change between "True" or "False" based on if it's valid or not in my javascript function.

```
function validateEventName(){
  const reEventName = /^[a-åA-Å0-9]{2,25}$/;
  if(!reEventName.test(inputEventName.value)) {
    inputEventName.classList.add("is-invalid");
    inputEventName.classList.remove("is-valid");
    inputEventName.checkValidity();
  } else {
    inputEventName.classList.remove("is-invalid")
    inputEventName.classList.add("is-valid")
  }
}
```

I need to be able to change the inputEventName.valididty.valid between "True" or "False" based on if it's valid or not with the function in my code above.

Comment: Just saying, I don't think reEventName does what you want it to do, because it matches ranges based off unicode values, so it matches all letters, some invisible control characters, a lot of uppercase diacriticals like Û.

Comment: @Aplet123 thanks for pointing it out, It's just a "placeholder" expression, the important thing is having the validity in place.

Answer (score 0):

use document.getElementById()

```
function validateEventName(){
      const reEventName = /^[a-åA-Å0-9]{2,25}$/;
      if(!reEventName.test(document.getElementById("dynamicID").value )) {
        inputEventName.classList.add("is-invalid");
        inputEventName.classList.remove("is-valid");
        inputEventName.checkValidity();
      } else {
        inputEventName.classList.remove("is-invalid")
        inputEventName.classList.add("is-valid")
      }
    }
```